# Why am I not able to add actionbar buttons?

Tags: java, android

Here is my action_bar_menu.xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_contactus"
    android:icon="@drawable/contact-us"
    android:title="@string/action_contactus"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Here is my activity_main.xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#232122"
tools:context="com.example.chintan.armour.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.093" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_lock-unlock"
    android:layout_width="278dp"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_rounded_button2"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="Lock/Unlock The Door"
    android:textColor="#26382F"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="53dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="55dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_bluetoothon"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="81dp"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_rounded_button"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="Turn Bluetooth On"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#BF360C"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="53dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="157dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_connect"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="81dp"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_rounded_button"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="Connect"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#BF360C"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="211dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="157dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_history"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="81dp"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_rounded_button"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="History"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#BF360C"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="53dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="279dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_configure"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="81dp"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_rounded_button"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="Configure"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#BF360C"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="211dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="279dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_aboutus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_rounded_button2"
    android:text="About us"
    android:textColor="#19251f"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="459dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_help"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_rounded_button2"
    android:text="Help"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#26382F"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="283dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="463dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is my MainActivity.java code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btonoff;
Button connect;
Button history;
Button configure;
Button lockunlock;
Button help;
Button aboutus;
BluetoothAdapter btadapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btonoff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_bluetoothon);
    connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);
    history = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_history);
    configure = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_configure);
    lockunlock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_lock_unlock);
    help = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_help);
    aboutus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_aboutus);

    btonoff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnClick(View view) {
            if(btadapter.isEnabled())
            {
                btadapter.disable();
            }
            else
            {
                btadapter.enable();
            }

        }

    });

}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_contactus) {

    }
}
}
```

Here is my styles.xml file :

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.Widget.TextView</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Widget"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Widget.TextView" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.TextView">
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf</item>
</style>



</resources>
```

And my AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.chintan.armour">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I read almost all the articles out there and all it says is everything that I have already done but I still don't get that contact-us icon on the action bar as I want to.

Comment: May you show your manifest and styles

Comment: You may be applying the wrong theme in the manifest file. Please update your question to include the manifest and styles.xml files.

Comment: Done @user1979221

Comment: Now what do i have to do? @Ayusch

Comment: @ChintanMehta, I think you have to return false in onCreateOptionsMenu

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I recommend doing.

1.Change your styles.xml :
change from darkActionBar to noActionBar theme.

2. Create a separate layout for toolbar with root element Toolbar
3. Include this newly created toolbar in activity_main.xml ( or whatever your mainactivity layout file is called) using the "include" tag ( google it if you are unaware.)
4. Find that toolbar by id in you MainActivity. For example :

   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
5. Set this toolbar as support action bar in onCreate method :

   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Compile and run the app finally !!

Answer (score 0):

`onCreateOptionsMenu()` should be like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Note the return statement which chains to the default implementation.